# Can gulp-rev inside individual tasks merge into one manifest?

Tags: gulp

Given these two tasks. I would like to have it so that each task can be run individually and the other tasks revision left in the manifest untouched.

```
gulp.task('testSiteScripts', function(){
var input = 'resources/assets/site/js/';
var output = 'public/site/js/';

gulp.src('public/build/site/js', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());

return gulp.src([
    'resources/assets/js/lib/jquery-2.2.0.js',
    'resources/assets/js/lib/bootstrap.js',
    input + 'app.js',
])
.pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
.pipe(rev())
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/site/js'))
.pipe(rev.manifest({merge: true}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/build'));
});
```

second task

```
gulp.task('testSiteCss', function(){
var input = 'resources/assets/site/css/';
var output = 'public/site/css/';

gulp.src('public/build/site/css', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());

return gulp.src([
    input + 'app.css',
])
.pipe(concat('all.css'))
.pipe(minifyCss())
.pipe(rev())
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/site/css'))
.pipe(rev.manifest({merge: true}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/build'));
});
```

Any idea if this can be done? This would prevent cache busting for assets that didn't change.

I have also tried

```
.pipe(rev.manifest('rev-manifest.json', {merge: true, base: './public/build'}))
```

and

```
.pipe(rev.manifest('rev-manifest.json', {merge: true, cwd: './public/build'}))
```

Which sort of works it adds the following line to the manifest.

```
"all.js": "all-336381325e.js"
```

which is wrong in my case it needs to be

```
"site/js/all.js": "all-336381325e.js"
```

Comment: Is that what you want to achieve: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev/issues/123 ?

Comment: That has some info but when I adjust the rev.manifest line to rev.manifest('./public/build/rev-manifest.json', {merge: true, base: './public/build'}) then it adds a new record to the manifest file. "all.js": "all-336381325e.js", which is wrong it should be "site/js/all.js": "all-336381325e.js",

Comment: you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same issue.  Pretty much did exactly what you've outlined above before finding your stackoverflow question while creating my own question, but now that it would be a duplicate I was hoping you might have found the answer.

Comment: Sorry but I have yet to find a solution. The gulp community is a bit lacking.